# How to compare two unequal nested lists based on the first and second item of the first list and get value or false

Tags: python, list

I am very new to python and I am trying to compare two nested lists based on the first two values of the lists. If the values match each other, then I want to get as an output the third value of the second list:

for example:

```
list_1 =[[600,700], [500,200], [100,250], [300,100]]
list_2 = [[600,700,"A"], [500,600,"B"], [100,250,"C"]]
```

I want to get:

```
list_new = ["A", false, "C", false]
```

I want to iterate through list_1 having as criteria the first two values of list_2. If the values match the I want the output to be the third value of list_2, otherwise false.

My thoughts on it (logic behind it):

```
for i in list_2
for m in list_1

if i[0]==m[0] and i[1]==m[1], then give me i[2]
else false
```

It would be great to get some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_1 =[[600,700], [500,200], [100,250], [300,100]]
list_2 = [[600,700,"A"], [500,600,"B"], [100,250,"C"]]

list_im_1 = {}
for x in list_2:
    list_im_1[(x[0],x[1])] = x[2]
result = []
for x in list_1:
    y = []
    y.extend(x)
    if tuple(x) in list_im_1:
        y.extend(list_im_1[tuple(x)])
    else:
        y.extend('False')
    result.append(y)
```

Comment: OP asked to get a list not print output

Comment: Thank you! How to modify this to append the value to list_1, so that my result is : list_1 =[[600,700,A], [500,200,false], [100,250,C], [300,100,false]]?

Comment: Thank you! It works great, the only think I had to change was adding square brackets to y.extend('False')  to  have it as one word: y.extend(['False'])

Answer (score 2):

With [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) function:

```
import itertools

list_1 =[[600,700], [500,200], [100,250], [300,100]]
list_2 = [[600,700,"A"], [500,600,"B"], [100,250,"C"]]
res = [l2[2] if (l1 and l2 and l1[:2] == l2[:2]) else False
       for l1, l2 in itertools.zip_longest(list_1, list_2)]
print(res)    # ['A', False, 'C', False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
list_1 =[[600,700], [500,200], [100,250], [300,100]] 
list_2 = [[600,700,"A"], [500,600,"B"], [100,250,"C"]]
list(map(lambda x, y: y[2] if y[:2]==x[:2] else False, list_1, list_2))
 + list(itertools.repeat(False, len(list_1) - len(list_2)))            
Out[12]: ['A', False, 'C', False]
```